# react-native-firebase display notification with image when app is not open

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase

I'll try to implement firebase cloud message in react native using `react-native-firebase`

An app is foreground notification is display with the image. but, when I close an app and send a notification, it displays only title & body massage, so anyone an idea how to do this...

[image]

Comment: Can you post some image or ui about it?

Comment: @Akshay Did you find solution for this. I am facing same issue.

Comment: looking for same

Comment: @Akshay Did you find the solution??

Comment: I've removed react-native-firebase and use https://onesignal.com